# Subform doesn't recognize textbox source after reopening file

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have one main form with a subform and two date text boxes. The subform has been connected to the query with a date value column. I put criteria in query `Between [Forms]![frm_mainform]![txt_from] And [Forms]![frm_mainform]![txt_to].` Also, both text boxes have `Default Value` set as  `=DateAdd("d";-30;Date())` and `=DateAdd("d";30;Date())`.

So, it works fine until I close the document and reopen it. After that subform doesn't recognize text boxes and lanch me entry boxes for both values.

[Data entry form pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki85Q.png)

After I change just one letter in `Name` it works again, and when I close the document again it lost it again.

Is anyone familiar with this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put `Me.Refresh` on `Form_Load()` event and it fixed it.

Still, I don't know what causes such behavior.

Comment: form references are buggy, replacing such references with simulated properties using public functions is my standard fix